# Mailchimp - How to make editable links

Tags: html, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a custom html newsletter for mailchimp. I created editable parts everywhere and it works just fine.
I also made a custom button and I would like to make its href attribute editable. When I add `mc:edit` on the `a` tag itself, I get to edit only the text content of the `a` tag. So I give `mc:edit` on the container `td` so that I can edit the a tag itself. This way I can edit the button but my client has to click on `<>` sign on the editor and edit manually the href attribute. This is not what I would like. I would like them to fill something like an input where all they have to do is to just paste url in there. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<a href="EDITABLE_URL" style="display: block; width: 114px; margin: 0 auto; color:white; text-align:center; text-decoration: none; text-transform: none; cursor: pointer;" target="_blank">Inscription</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take the url pasted in and then pass the html back to the form. For example:

`<span mc:edit="chat_button_"></span>` would be replaced with

`<a class="mcnButton " title="Chat Now" href="destination" target="_blank" style="font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;">Chat Now</a>`